# Php PDO error handling on production server

Tags: php, pdo

Should i use try catch for every conn statements and do i need to set this every time during query execution

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Can some one please tell me the better approach to execute queries using pdo in a better way with general  error displaying to user

Comment: 1. Set errmode exception once. 2. Either use a **single** global try catch or an exception handler to handle the error according to the environment

Comment: 2. Either use a single global try catch, can you please explain with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never echo out your errors in production. Use a try catch statement and then log it to a file.

```
try {
//your whole application code here
} catch( Exception $e)  {
error_log($e);//log the actual error
echo 'an unexpected error occurred';//send generic error message 
exit; 
}
```

Also you don't need to set attribute for every query.  I assume you're not initializing the connection everytime. You can always initialize the connection in a file and include it where you need it. Thereby setting attribute once

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense for the improvement. Also learnt alot from the duplicate marked as well.